# Which approach is better for finding the frequency of element in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an array list and inserted few elements in random.I was trying to find the frequency of occurences of each element.I tried with two approaches and both worked fine.The first method is using a straight forward method available in JAVA i.e,

```
  Collection.frequency(collection,"element");
```

The second approach is that putting the ArrayList elements into a HashMap and finding the frequency

```
    List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
    elements.add("A");
    elements.add("B");
    elements.add("C");
    elements.add("A");

    Map<String,Integer> count = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    for(String s : elements)
    {
        if(count.containsKey(s))
        {
            count.put(s,count.get(s)+1);
        }
        else
        {
            count.put(s, 1);
        }
    }
```

Both the approaches are working fine.But I wanted to know which is a better approach to follow.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on how often you need to get the frequency information - if it is a one off the `Collections::frequency` approach is fine otherwise a map will be more efficient. Also note that with Java 8 you could save a few lines of code with:

```
Map<String, Long> count = elements.stream().collect(groupingBy(e -> e, counting()));
```

<sub>*assumes the following imports:

`import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;`

`import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;`*</sub>

Comment: This is a cool suggestion... However it also impies that he uses Java 8... :)

Comment: @Martin - I think the OP is a *she* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind... LOL, I should really always use "the OP" instead of "he/she"... :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you are going to require the frequency of elements in your List multiple times, using the Map would be more efficient, since `Collections.frequency` iterates the entire list each time you call it, while searching for a key in the Map takes constant time.

If you only need to know the frequency of few elements, and very rarely, and your list is not too large, using the existing method won't be too bad, and it's definitely easier than maintaining a Map of frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is a little bit vague, a better approach based on what?

As Eran points out, if you are concerned about performance and you will be making this call many times then the HashMap will save you time. But if not, then just using frequency should be a lot more clear and will clutter up your code less, so I think in general using the former would be preferred. In general you want to be using methods that already exist over reproducing them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your Map approach is fine if you need the frequency of many or all your elements as you only iterate the list once. However, the Map is just a snapshot of the List Frequency at the time you called it, updating it would be more complicated than recalculating if the list changes...

At the end, if you are working with small lists, you shouldn't care about performance issues. I would think that this will only affect if you have thousands of elements in the list, or if this function is called many times per second (some live service).

In any other situation, you will hardly have to think about which approach is better as it won't really matter.

On the other hand, your question states that you need the frequency of each element... So, in the List, you first need to create a Set so you get the unique elements, and then apply the Collections.frequency() method... Taking this into account, I would really use the Map approach, or in Java8 the much more cooler stream approach...